# Image animate function not working in fabric js?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am using fabric js for canvas animation and I am created canvas with id 'canvas' then put image in it and set left position to zero. It's working fine but animate function is not working.

Please help me.

**My code:**

**HTML:**

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="990" height="285">
    This text is displayed if your browser 
    does not support HTML5 Canvas.  
</canvas>
```

**javascript:**

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

var image = new Image();
image.src = 'images/body.png';

var bugBody = fabric.Image.fromURL(image.src, function (oImg) {
    canvas.add(oImg);
        oImg.set('left',0)
});

bugBody.animate('left', 200, {
    onChange: canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas)
});
```

Thanking You.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that this happen because your image is not complete loaded.

So, you can put your animation code inside your callback function.

Check this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9x9Qc/

Like this:

```
var srcImg = "http://fabricjs.com/lib/pug.jpg";

// canvas
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

fabric.Image.fromURL(srcImg, function (oImg) {
    canvas.add(oImg);
    oImg.set('left',0);
    oImg.set('top', 100);
    oImg.scale(.25);
    canvas.renderAll();

    // and then, we can animate the image    
    oImg.animate('left', 200, {
        onChange: canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas)
    });
});
```